# can i integrate team explorer everywhere and intellij 15.02?

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs, tee, intellij-14

we are trying to use tfs2012 as a Version Control and Intellij 15.02/14.04 as IDE for Java Projects. been trying to integrate TFS2012 and intellij, was successful in that part, but unable to find some kind of integration with team explorer everywhere in intellij.Is it possible to integrate Team explorer everywhere with Intellij Idea 14.04 or 15.02.

Comment: Did you try searching on the web? Seriously, this is the first link that came up on Google: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-tfs-integration.html

Comment: that link which you gave me just talks about integration (which i already read). I already specified that i was successful in integrating. i was asking about Team Explorer Everywhere for Intellij IDEA not the integration. thanks for your time

Comment: Define: "Unable to find some kind of integration"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There never was a "Team Explorer for IntelliJ", there used to be native integration from JetBrains and in [October Microsoft has released the Team Services plugin for IntelliJ](https://java.visualstudio.com/Downloads/intellijplugin/Index).

If you're looking for Work item integration, that is not part of the new plugin. Instead, use the Web UI, which is a rich experience and supports everything the Eclipse Plugin can.

If you're looking for TFVC support, that doesn't seem to be part of it either. It is probably on the backlog, but for now you're going to have to use the [native TFS integration from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-tfs-integration.html). The new plugin supports Git on TFS and Team Services only.

I suspect that TFVC integration will come in the future, but I can only speculate on that part.